# SQL Solr query Convert date to

Tags: sql, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I'm interested in the question: how to convert date to number in millis with Solr SQL? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Function Queries (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html)

For example: in the field returned by your query, just insert ms(2000-01-01T00:00:00Z) or ms(mydatefield)

http://localhost:8983/solr/job/select?fl=ms(2000-01-01T00:00:00Z)&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json

result: 946684800000

Obs2: Dates are relative to midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC (you can use function queries and calculate milliseconds between to dates)

Obs1: your date field type (mydatefield in the above example) should be a TrieDateField